# Modelling data common to many tables

Tags: database-design

I have a dynamic data model with potentially thousands of entity tables, let's call them E1, E2, ..., or generally EX.

There is also a small number of utility tables, that contain data that may be attached to these entities, for example an audit table or an 'attached documents' table, let's call them U1,U2, ..., or generally UX.

The relation for each pair EX-UX is 1 to many (for example each instance in E1 may have several attached documents, but each document is attached to just one instance in any EX).

The basic problem is that each UX contains rows that reference different tables EX.

There are several ways to model this relation:

**The Link Table solution**

Create a link table for each pair of EX/UX. For example:

```
E1_U1 (
    E1_ID FK TO E1
    U1_ID FK TO U1
)
```

- Pros: Clean. No change to the model of EX
- Cons: Explosion in the number of tables, we could just as well create an instance of each utility table for each entity. If I need a reverse lookup, e.g. show me the instance in EX which is referenced by some instance in U1, I need to search through all link tables EX_U1.

**The Entity Table solution**

Create a new Table ENTITY which contains one column ENTITY_ID, which is a unique id for each row in any EX. In this model it would make sense to replace the primary key of each EX with ENTITY_ID.

```
ENTITY (
    ENTITY_ID PK
)

E1 (
    ENTITY_ID PK, FK TO ENTITY
    ...
)

U1 (
    U1_ID PK
    ENTITY_ID FK TO ENTITY
    ...
)
```

- Pros: I guess this is the standard way to model inheritance
- Cons: Significantly changes the data model and application logic. 
  Reverse lookup possible only by searching through all EX for the right ENTITY_ID.

**The 'Typed Foreign Key' Solution**

Give each UX two columns as a 'typed foreign key': ETABLE_ID and ETABLE_ROW_ID. ETABLE_ID references the table (i.e which EX), ETABLE_ROW_ID the row in this table.

In my model this is possible, because

- I am already keeping a meta model of my entity tables in the application logic, thus ETABLE_ID is readily available
- ETABLE_ROW_ID is guaranteed to be of the same type for all E

> ```
> U1 (
>     U1_ID PK
>     ETABLE_ID FK TO ETABLE
>     ETABLE_ROW_ID 
>     ...
> )
> ```

- Pros: No change to the model of EX. Reverse lookup can be easily implemented in application logic.
- Cons: The problem is obviously that we cannot apply a foreign key constraint to ETABLE_ROW_ID.

While it's not clean relational design, I still favor the last solution, because it has practical advantages. The lost referential integrity I could model within the application logic.

What is the preferred solution for this problem? Any experience/recommendations?

Comment: How about a composite key in U containing the unique entity_id from E, the foreign key to the row in E1 (or Ex), and a sequential ID column in U? This would allow you to have only one U for any number of entities.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. With 'unique entity_id from E' do you mean the 'ENTITY Table' solution? I cleaned up the EX/UX nomenclature in the question a little, to make discussing this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Entity Table solution with type:**

```
ENTITY (
    ENTITY_ID PK,
    ENTITY_TYPE,
    UNIQUE KEY (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_TYPE)
)

E1 (
    ENTITY_ID PK, 
    ENTITY_TYPE, constrained to value '1'
    FK (ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_TYPE) TO ENTITY table    
    ...
)

U1 (
    U1_ID PK
    ENTITY_ID FK TO ENTITY
    ...
)
```

The advantage of storing the type in the ENTITY table is that you don't have to search all E tables to find out what type it is.

Each E table constrains its own type to a fixed value, so naturally any row in E1 can reference only ENTITY rows with the type=1.

See also:

- My past answers to the [`polymorphic-associations`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:20860%20%5Bpolymorphic-associations%5D) tag
- My presentation [Practical Object Oriented Models In SQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql)
- My book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)